# ¿Como fijar los componentes de un div en toda la anchura de la pantalla sin hacer scroll?

Tags: css, html5, bootstrap, bootstrap-4, material-design

Tengo un problema para fijar los componentes al 100% del ancho de la pantalla, y hay un componente que queda por fuera y hay que hacer scroll, necesito que no se tenga que hacer scroll estuve investigando editando las lineas de css, pero no doy con la solución.

Está hecho con bootstrap 4 agradezco sugerencias o otros enlaces donde resolver..

Cuando edito regularmente al cambiar de dispositivo se rompe de nuevo el diseño y evidentemente tiene sentido, porque la estoy adaptando a mi pantalla. No recuerdo alguna clase que me ayude para esto, quizás el problema sea como está estructurado.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <!-- Compiled and minified Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <!-- Minified JS library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Compiled and minified Bootstrap JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    .carousel-item {
      height: 100vh;
      min-height: 350px;
      background: no-repeat center center scroll;
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
    }
    
    .navbar {
      background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Navigation -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo canino</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Inicio
                                <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">American Bully</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Bulldog Francés</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Bulldog Inglés</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Web principal</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <header id="header">
    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <!-- Slide One - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
        <div class="carousel-item active" style="background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/6yOg6cEHmgs/1920x1080')">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h2 class="display-4">Bully bravo</h2>
            <p class="lead">
              Lorem, ipsum dolor.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Slide Two - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
        <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/JSfsK9VH4q8/1920x1080')">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h2 class="display-4">Bully bravo</h2>
            <p class="lead">
              Lorem, ipsum dolor.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Slide Three - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
        <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/E9VhlOb9gmk/1920x1080')">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h2 class="display-4">Bully bravo</h2>
            <p class="lead">
              Lorem, ipsum dolor.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
    <footer id="sticky-footer" class="py-4 bg-dark text-white-50">
      <div class="container text-center">
        <small>Copyright &copy; Your Website</small>
      </div>
    </footer>
  </header>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el componente que queda por fuera? No veo que se reproduzca el error que mencionas con tu código. Por favor visita: [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Como anotación, estás llamando en tu cabecera los scripts de jQuery y Bootstrap para su versión 3. Quítalos y deja únicamente los que están antes del cierre de la etiqueta body

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia, corregí lo de la repetición de llamada, para poder ver el que queda por fuera tienes que abrir la pagina en pantalla completa dale click a pantalla completa despues de ejecutar, allí podrás ver a lo que me refiero.. leeré el post que me compartiste